# Nurbs curve linking to armature

Tags: armature, parent

Hi I have made a stick man that looks like wiring using nurbs curve and a cirlce to bevel the wire frame man (Extruding using a face in most programmes). I have made an armature but now notice to parent the wire frame man to the armature it does not work. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: could you please show some screenshots? If your character is made with a curve you could hook the curve vertices to some bones (create an armature, switch to Pose mode, select the bone you want, shift select your curve, select the vertex you want, ctrl H > Hook to Selected Bone), but you can not parent it to an armature with a simple With Automatic Weight, to do so you must convert your character to mesh...

Comment: thanks @moonboots I will give it a go, I don't know how to post a pic?